# install filezilla on ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, filezilla

I run on:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (beaver-osp1-varys X34)
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

When I try to install filezilla I get an error:

```
$ sudo apt install filezilla
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
filezilla is already the newest version (3.28.0-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apt-clone archdetect-deb btrfs-tools dmraid gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0
  gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 gir1.2-xkl-1.0 kactivities-bin kactivitymanagerd
  kinit kio kpartx kpartx-boot libdebian-installer4 libdmraid1.0.0.rc16
  libfwup1 libhfstospell9 libido3-0.1-0 libkf5activities5
  libkf5activitiesstats1 libkf5attica5 libkf5bookmarks-data libkf5bookmarks5
  libkf5completion-data libkf5completion5 libkf5doctools5
  libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel5
  libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5
  libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5solid5
  libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5
  libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data
  libkf5xmlgui5 libllvm9 libnvidia-cfg1-440 libnvidia-cfg1-450
  libnvidia-common-440 libnvidia-common-450 libnvidia-compute-440
  libnvidia-compute-450 libnvidia-compute-450:i386 libnvidia-decode-440
  libnvidia-decode-450 libnvidia-decode-450:i386 libnvidia-encode-440
  libnvidia-encode-450 libnvidia-encode-450:i386 libnvidia-extra-440
  libnvidia-extra-450 libnvidia-fbc1-440 libnvidia-fbc1-450
  libnvidia-fbc1-450:i386 libnvidia-gl-440 libnvidia-gl-450
  libnvidia-gl-450:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-440 libnvidia-ifr1-450
  libnvidia-ifr1-450:i386 libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libtimezonemap-data
  libtimezonemap1 libvoikko1 linux-headers-oem-osp1
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-58 linux-oem-osp1-headers-5.0.0-1050
  linux-oem-osp1-headers-5.0.0-1068 linux-oem-osp1-headers-5.0.0-1069
  nvidia-compute-utils-440 nvidia-compute-utils-450 nvidia-dkms-440
  nvidia-dkms-450 nvidia-kernel-common-440 nvidia-kernel-common-450
  nvidia-kernel-source-440 nvidia-kernel-source-450 nvidia-utils-440
  nvidia-utils-450 python3-icu python3-pam rdate shim sonnet-plugins
  ubuntu-web-launchers xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-450
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up tlp-config (4) ...
Leaving 'diversion of /etc/default/tlp to /etc/default/tlp.template by tlp-config'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/tlp-config", line 3, in <module>
    from configobj import ConfigObj
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configobj'
dpkg: error processing package tlp-config (--configure):
 installed tlp-config package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tlp-config
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please, don't tell me I have to upgrade ubuntu because I always crap my pants when I think of it. (OR at least advise me on how to do it, please...)

EDIT
Some more info on my system

```
$ apt-cache policy tlp-config
tlp-config:
  Installed: 4
  Candidate: 4
  Version table:
 *** 4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ dpkg -S configobj | grep ".py$"
python-configobj: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configobj.py

$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              12
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-11
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  6
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               165
Model name:          Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             800.018
CPU max MHz:         5000.0000
CPU min MHz:         800.0000
BogoMIPS:            5199.98
Virtualization:      VT-x
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            256K
L3 cache:            12288K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-11
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp pku ospke md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
```

Comment: Why not just install it from the Software Store? Works fine just did it 2 days ago.

Comment: @David noice! it works! never used software store before :p

Comment: Now do the sudo apt update and after it is done sudo apt upgrade you are behinds in up dates.

Comment: This^^^ or alternatively `sudo apt full-upgrade` to clean up most of those orphaned packages.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy tlp-config` and `dpkg -S configobj | grep ".py$"`. What is *beaver-osp1-varys X34*? What is your CPU architecture?

Comment: Did you install a different python version ?

Comment: yes, in my base environment I have Python 3.8.3